# Different implementation of classes

Tags: java, oop

Below are the implementation of two classes `Temp1` and `Temp2`.
 I want to know
`Temp2` class is better than `Temp1` because of reducing redundancy of code.
Is there some more advantage using `Temp2` class instead of `Temp1`?

**Temp1:**

```
    class Temp1 {

    String var1, var2, var3, var4;

    method1()
    {
    var1 = "m1_1";
    var2 = "m1_2";
    var3 = "m1_3";
    var4 = "m1_4";
    }

    method2()
    {
    var1 = "m2_1";
    var2 = "m2_2";
    var3 = "m2_3";
    var4 = "m2_4";  
    }

    method3(a,b,c,d)
    {
    var1 = a;
    var2 = b;
    var3 = c;
    var4 = d;   
    }

}
```

**Temp2:**

```
class Temp2 {

String var1, var2, var3, var4;

method1()
{
assign_values("m1_1","m1_2","m1_3","m1_4");
}

method2()
{
assign_values("m2_1","m2_2","m2_3","m2_4");
}

method3(a,b,c,d)
{
assign_values(a,b,c,d);
}

assign_values(p,q,r,s){
var1 = p;
var2 = q;
var3 = r;
var4 = s;
}

}
```

Comment: I would suggest that having internal methods that update instance variables is almost always preferable so one can implement checking on the potential variables. In the `assign_values()` method, one could ensure that `p` is < 100, for example. In the class `temp1`, that checking would have to be duplicated.

Comment: This is a codereview-question. Its off-topic in stackoverflow IMO. Please  close and reopen at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `method3(...)` and `assign_values(...)` do exactly the same thing.  You don't need both.

Comment: @PeterRader: What makes you think this a codereview question? sujeet14108 shows us two constructed code samples and asks about the pros and cons.

Comment: @FrankPuffer imo he like us to review for best-practice and have working code without *problems*. Would it be more specific it better goes to programmers.stackexchange.com but its a little bit too abstract so, I would agree http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265928 that guide us to move it to a different site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement it like this to reduce redundancy (converted to some valid Java code):

```
public class Temp {

    public String var1, var2, var3, var4;

    public void method1() {
        method3("m1_1", "m1_2", "m1_3", "m1_4");
    }

    public void method2() {
        method3("m2_1", "m2_2", "m2_3", "m2_4");
    }

    public void method3(String a, String b, String c, String d)
    { 
        var1 = a;
        var2 = b;
        var3 = c;
        var4 = d;    
    }
}
```

Of course the class doesn't really make much sense and all variable and method names are badly chosen, but that's probably not your point.

Actually all three methods should probably be implemented as constructors. The only issue is that you cannot have two different default constructors (the ones with no arguments). But you could use factory methods:

```
public class Temp {

    public String var1, var2, var3, var4;

    public static Temp method1() {
        return new Temp("m1_1", "m1_2", "m1_3", "m1_4");
    }

    public static Temp method2() {
        return new Temp("m2_1", "m2_2", "m2_3", "m2_4");
    }

    public Temp(String a, String b, String c, String d)
    { 
        var1 = a;
        var2 = b;
        var3 = c;
        var4 = d;    
    }
}
```